# python: Unable to open json file from another directory?

Tags: python, path, pytest, relative-path

My tests are at:

`src/com/xyz/tests/api_test/<Test File>`

My test file calls my libraries at:

`src/com/xyz/libs/api_libs/<Library File>`

My library file has to open a JSON file at:

`src/com/xyz/libs/api_libs/configs/<Config File>`

In my library file, since its at the same parent directory as the JSON configs, I have used the following code to open the JSON.

```
with open('configs/sample_wlan_json'):
    <Do Some action>
```

I tried various paths like:

```
.../libs/api_libs/configs/<ConfigFileName>

src/com/mist/libs/api_libs/configs/<ConfigFileName>.json

The whole path from /Users/...... but nothing seems to work.
```

Comment: I think you need to add an extension of the JSON file like demo.json not demo_json

Comment: absolute path should always work. check your file name and try again.

Comment: @MohitChandel It was a type. I was using the right extension.

Comment: @marxmacher Thanks, was a file name issue. But I dont want to use absolute path in my code? The relative path doesnt seem to work. (tried various formats)

Comment: use pathlib https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Answer (score 1):

A relative path is relative to the current working directory. Current working directory depends on how an application is started, and not where it is.

So, if you want to have a path relative to your source code, you should not rely on the current working directory, but construct the absolute path instead.

You can construct a path which is relative to your source code by using the `__file__` variable, which is the path to the current py file.

Something like this should work:

```
configs_dir = os.path.join(__file__, '..', 'configs')

with open(os.path.join(configs_dir, 'sample_wlan.json'), 'rt') as f:
   ...
```